# Two accounts from the same IP for different people?

Tags: support

My sister and I would like to have separate accounts. But I see that StackExchange allows only one account per IP address. In that case, how do we do it? We really don’t want to ask questions from the same account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But I see that StackExchange only allows one account per IP address.

This isn't true; both of you are welcome to create your own accounts

However, please do not vote on each other's posts, as otherwise we might find vote abuse to have taken place.

Comment: Ah, that's not at all a problem. Great news for us. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Is it really true that SE site policy discourages people sharing an IP address from "cross-voting"? I can see that if mods have to allow for that, it makes the job a bit more laborious. But assuming there would never be that many "genuine" cases, it seems unlikely it would become truly burdensome.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's somewhat discouraged, because (1) it's hard for us to distinguish between sockpuppeting and genuine voting, and we'd prefer not to warn accounts when we shouldn't have, and (2) in such cases, the voting is often disproportionate, since you know the other person and you're more likely to vote for him/her than in other cases.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Two people sharing an IP address probably share many other things, including attitudes to language usage. So all other things being equal, any upvotes for each other are inherently less meaningful than any random pair of users. The policy as you've set it out seems sound to me!

Comment: You mean people run socks from the same IP?  What in the world are they thinking?

Comment: How does SE handle cases where an entire company or school is behind one public-facing IP address?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Same way, I think. They shouldn't vote for each other's posts.

Comment: @Alenanno, sometimes we might not even know about each other.  For example, my employer has more than 10,000 people in diverse locations all hitting one web proxy, so to the outside world we're all the same IP address.  If we had more users on the same SE sites we wouldn't necessarily even know who each other are.  (I don't think we have too many on EL&U, but I'll bet we do on SO and others.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oh... I'm sure there is an answer to that, but I'm not the right person for this. Try asking a Team member. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sharing the same IP doesn't automatically mean sharing the same language attitudes. When I go to visit my American friend, I am using her IP address, but her language attitudes are quite different from mine.

Comment: @Alenanno If your company's web proxy is well-behaved and uses the right forwarding headers, I would hope there would be no problem: it should be obvious that it is a proxy.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of this advice (to try not to vote for people sharing the same IP). So I suspect that much more casual users ill be unlikely to follow this advice, and also, it should be very difficult for casual (or even long time users) to be aware of sharing their IP address and who they might be sharing it with. This advice seems ostensibly correct but pretty difficult for users to know how to implement beside even knowing to implement it.